# Debugging .dmp files from WinDbg in Visual Studio 2008 for .Net managed apps

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windbg

I am trying to find how to take a crash dump of a .Net managed executable and then open the resulting .dmp file in Visual Studio 2008. I want to see where in the source code the exception is thrown, the call stack and the value of variables in functions on the stack.

To simplify the problem, I've written a mini-app that crashes:

...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int a = 2;           //Variable I want to see value for when debugging

        if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Crasher\bin\Debug\file.txt")) //Doesn't exist
            throw new FileNotFoundException();     //Unhandled exception thrown
    }
}
```

...

I did a DEBUG build and ran it from outside Visual Studio. In windbg, I clicked "Attach to Process" and selected my app. Then I typed in the windbg command window:

```
          .dump /ma C:\crasher\bin\debug\dump.dmp
```

Then I opened the .dmp file in Visual Studio. I went to Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and added the following:

```
          http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols  (saved to local folder)
```

This gives me symbols for all of the DLLs listed in the Modules window (e.g. Kernel32.dll, gdi32.dll - I think all of them listed are native) with the exception of mscorlib.ni.dll. The Microsoft Symbol Server gives me symbols builds and .pdbs for mscorlib.dll but NOT mscorlib.ni.dll.

When I try to load the .pdb for my .exe itself, it tells me it does not match the app. I think this is because the .exe is managed and we don't yet have symbols for all of the native code beneath it - i.e. if I could get a symbols build and pdb for mscorlib.ni.dll this would work.

Is this reasoning correct? Am I missing something else?

Either way, why is mscorlib.ni.dll not available on the Microsoft Symbol Server, where can I get symbol information and is there anything else I should know for debugging managed code through crash dumps in Visual Studio.

Many thanks - any help will be appreciated.

Phil Whittington

Comment: Isn't the dmp of the JIT compiled code? Will that work?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Will what work? I used passed the /ma param to the windbg .dump command like so: 

.dump /ma C:\crasher\bin\debug\dump.dmp

I am so close in Visual Studio that I can't believe it's not possible. Various online sources hint at it being possible, without being thorough enouch in the steps I'd need to take.


Thanks for your comments

Comment: Why do you want to use Visual Studio for this anyway? WinDBG is far more powerful.

Comment: I don't know how to do what we want in windbg either :) I need to see where the app has stopped in our code plus the call stack and variables. We would find that easier to do from within an IDE.

Comment: There is no way you can do this in VS2008. With VS 2010 (Ultimate I think) you can certainly do this. Your best bet is to use WinDbg. Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/05/18/601002.aspx?PageIndex=2

Comment: It's not going to be easy, but if you can get used to using WinDbg then you will have a VERY powerful tool in your arsenal.

Comment: Another good link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558221/diassemble-managed-code-issue

Comment: [See This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919943/visual-studio-and-windbg-which-one-is-better-to-debug-large-scale-managed-applic/1919966#1919966)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason Evans says in his comment, this is not supported in VS2008, but you can do it in WinDbg.

The easiest way to get a correct dump for a crash like this is to use adplus (which is included in Debugging Tools for Windows). There are various options, but to get a crash dump based on the process name, you could do

```
>adplus -crash -o c:\dumpdirectory -pn app.exe
```

This will give you two dumps. One for the first chance exception and one for the second. In this case they will be virtually identical, but for a more realistic scenario the first chance exception dump will show you the state of the application when the exception was thrown (i.e. before any exception handling occur). The second chance exception dump will show you the state of the unhandled exception.

To get the exception, open the crash dump and load SOS by typing `.loadby sos mscorwks`.

Then use the `!pe` command to print the exception on the current thread (which will be the faulting thread in this case). It will look something like this:

```
0:000> !pe
Exception object: 024a5114
Exception type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Message: Unable to find the specified file.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    0020F0F0 005100D6 TestBench!TestBench.Program.Main()+0x66

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80070002
```

To list the local variable `a` use `!clrstack -l`, but keep in mind that locals are rarely available in a release mode builds due to optimizations.

```
0:000> !clrstack -l
OS Thread Id: 0x1a50 (0)
ESP       EIP     
0020f04c 7571b727 [HelperMethodFrame: 0020f04c] 
0020f0f0 005100d6 TestBench.Program.Main()
    LOCALS:
        0x0020f0fc = 0x00000002  <--- the value of a
        0x0020f0f8 = 0x00000000

0020f328 51141b5c [GCFrame: 0020f328]
```

Comment: Brian, thank you very much for this - I haven't tried this yet, but wanted to respond. Will post further if any other queries come up :) Thanks again. PW

Comment: @Phil you're welcome. Be sure to check out the questions tagged with WinDbg/SOS as some of them may be helpful if you're going to learn WinDbg.